# Create relationship and node if not exist

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have the graph with organizations and employees with 2 types of relationships:
`(:Employee)-[:Worked]->(:Organization)`
`(:Employee)-[:Managed]->(:Organization)`

Organization has unique property `Id` with index on it. Employee have property `Name` without index. I need to add new Employee to organization if he is not exist, or only add new relationship if he is exist. But i dont know how acheive this without index on `Name`.
1. Find organization by Id. Ok, this is fast.
`match (o:Organization {Id:1})`
2. Find employee that already linked to organization or add new link and employee if not exist. I cant use simple
`merge (e:Employee {Name: "name"})`
`merge (e)-[:Worked]->(o)`
 because i dont have index on `Name`(this is will be slow) and i need find only employee that connected to selected organization
`merge (e:Employee { Name: "name" })-[:Worked]->(o)` doesnt work - it will add new employee if there is already exist employee with that name but other relationship, `[:Managed]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding the requirements for `MERGE`. An index is not required for `MERGE` to work.

In your specific case, having an index on `:Employee(Name)` is not required in order for `MERGE (e:Employee {Name: "name"})` to work as expected. However, having such an index *will* speed up the processing of that `MERGE` clause, so it is recommended.

Comment: I know that index is not required for merge, it is required for fast search node in case it is exist. But index on big property Name will be overhead  and i need this type of search: "search for employee with Name=name that linked to organization with Id=id"

Comment: The overhead is encountered when adding/removing the indexed node (or changing the indexed property value). Those occurrences are usually rare compared to the number of times you need to do a match (which is when you get the speed boost). So, unless you have a rare situation, I would just add the index. At least try it out to see if there is an overall speedup. You can always drop the index if you find out it hurts your performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few simple things to understand about how Neo4j handles Cypher MERGE operations to avoid undesired or unexpected behavior when using it.

1. The Cypher MERGE operation is a MATCH or CREATE of the entire pattern. This means that if any element of the pattern does NOT exist, Neo4j will attempt to create the entire pattern.
2. Always MERGE on each segment of the pattern that has the possibility to already exist.
3. After a MERGE operation you are guaranteed to have a useable reference to all identifiers established during the Cypher MERGE operation because they were either found or created.

Merge in CQL dosent require any index on the node. you can try the following :

merge (:Employee)-[:< relation_name >]->(:Organization)

If the nodes specified are existing, the  relation among them is created else new nodes would be created and the relation among them is created .

Comment: And also new node wil be created if employee exist but connected to organization with other relation.